# Cannot read into array JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is the string: `[{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"1567613277000":10541}],"sid":"780160","units":"W","age":5},{"cid":"PWER_SUB","data":[{"1567613272000":384}],"sid":"780630","units":"W","age":10}]` I can't get the value our for Data

I have tried looping through the array with no luck

```
$arr = json_decode($j,true);
    echo $arr[0][0];
```

Just returns an error

I am trying to get 1567613277000":10541 as the result.

Comment: Because the inner arrays are an associative array, not a numerical array. Have you done `var_dump($arr);`?

Comment: Be useful to share the error message.

Comment: You must try this echo $arr[0]['data'][0]['1567613277000']; as it's an associative array.

Comment: The last number changes all the time , I am trying to write its result to a Database every minute, I m not sure how to read into an associative array, if I use $arr[0][0] it says Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 9

Comment: I also get Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/index.php on line 12
everytime I try different ways of access the array echo "<br/><br/>";
 echo $arr[5]["data"];
 echo "<br/><br/>";
 echo $arr[4]['data'];

Comment: I'd suggest using [`array_key_first()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) to find out the first key in the `data` array, then you can access the value that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share functional code with you since you are struggling. This question has really been answered in the comments though. Encourage you to also vote it a duplicate question and close it up.

```
<?php
$json = '[{
    "cid": "PWER",
    "data": [{
        "1567613277000": 10541
    }],
    "sid": "780160",
    "units": "W",
    "age": 5
}, {
    "cid": "PWER_SUB",
    "data": [{
        "1567613272000": 384
    }],
    "sid": "780630",
    "units": "W",
    "age": 10
}]';

$a = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
  $foo = $v['data'][0];
  $fooKey = key($foo);
  $fooValue = reset($foo);

  var_dump('key:' . $fooKey, 'value:' . $fooValue);
}
```

Remember `var_dump` is your friend. It's just an array that looks complicated because of the nesting. Iterate and dump, step by step, you can manage any array no matter how complex.

Comment: Thanks you very much !!!